# given a set closed under finite complementation and union; disprove closeness under countable union and intersection

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, random-walk

The collection $\mathscr{A}$ of subsets of $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\infty}$ is given by
$$\mathscr{A}=\{S\times\Omega:S\subseteq\{0,1\}^{l},l\ge1\}$$
Then, $\mathscr{A}$ is closed under complementation, finite union and hence, finite intersection.

> If $A_1,A_2...\in\mathscr{A}$, is
>   $(i)$ ${\underset{n=1}{\stackrel{\infty}{\bigcup}}}A_n\in\mathscr{A}$ ?
>   $(ii)$ ${\underset{n=1}{\stackrel{\infty}{\bigcap}}}A_n\in\mathscr{A}$ ?

Somehow, intuitively the answer is no because here, we consider countable union and intersection rather than finite union and intersection. But, I can't think of a theorem supporting this claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0,0,\cdots,0\} \times \Omega$ (where there  are $n$ zeros) is in $\mathscr{A}$ for each $n$ but the intersection of these is not in$\mathscr{A}$. For unions just take complements of these sets.